# Decorator - viewpoint mapping assertion error

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

I have a flask app with several end points and I have written a decorator to log the end points for audit purpose. The decorator works fine when I tried with one end point but when I add the decorator to a second end point, I am facing assertion error

For Example, I have two end points to edit and delete

```
@route('/owners/<ownerid>/delete',methods=['DELETE'])
@logtrail()
def deleteOwner(ownerid):
     if request.method == 'DELETE':
         return jsonify({})

@route('/owners/<ownerid>/edit',methods=['PUT'])
@logtrail()
def editOwner(ownerid):
     if request.method == 'PUT':
         return jsonify({})
```

The decorator @logtrail works fine either for edit or delete edit point but the app fails to start if add the decorator to both end points

Decorator code is as below

```
def logtrail(usermsg=None):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            print "Audit code goes here"
            return func(**kwargs)
        return wrap
    return decorator
```

Exact error which I get when I start the application is

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: wrap
```

From error message, I get the name has to be unique like method names but how can I do that in a decorator?

Any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a decorator without the wrap will rename the function, which will cause the issue you mentioned - since there will be more than one function with the same name.

> (...) A decorator is a function that returns a function. The only thing you have to keep in mind when implementing something like this is to update the __name__, __module__ and some other attributes of a function. This is often forgotten, but you don’t have to do that by hand, there is a function for that that is used like a decorator (functools.wraps()).

(http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/viewdecorators/).

Try to change your decorator to the following:

```
from functools import wraps

def logtrail(usermsg=None):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            print "Audit code goes here"
            return func(**kwargs)
        return wrap
    return decorator
```

Comment: Yes figured that out and added this to the code  wrap.__name__ = func.func_name which solved my issue